# C++ strange jump in unsigned long long int values

Tags: c++, algorithm, unsigned-long-long-int

I have the following question, which is actually from a coding test I recently took:

### Question:

A function `f(n) = a*n + b*n*(floor(log(n)/log(2))) + c*n*n*n` exists.

At a particular value, let `f(n) = k`;

Given `k, a, b, c`, find `n`.

For a given value of `k`, if no `n` value exists, then return 0.

### Limits:

```
1 <= n < 2^63-1
0 < a, b < 100
0 <= c < 100
0 < k < 2^63-1
```

The logic here is that since `f(n)` is purely increasing for a given a, b and c, I can find `n` by binary search.

The code I wrote was as follows:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

unsigned long long logToBase2Floor(unsigned long long n){
    return (unsigned long long)(double(log(n))/double(log(2)));
}

#define f(n, a, b, c) (a*n + b*n*(logToBase2Floor(n)) + c*n*n*n)


unsigned long long findNByBinarySearch(unsigned long long k, unsigned long long a, unsigned long long b, unsigned long long c){
    unsigned long long low = 1;
    unsigned long long high = (unsigned long long)(pow(2, 63)) - 1;
    unsigned long long n;
    while(low<=high){
        n = (low+high)/2;
        cout<<"\n\n          k= "<<k;
        cout<<"\n f(n,a,b,c)= "<<f(n,a,b,c)<<"  low = "<<low<<"  mid="<<n<<"  high = "<<high;
        if(f(n,a,b,c) == k)
            return n;
        else if(f(n,a,b,c) < k)
            low = n+1;
        else high = n-1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I then tried it with a few test cases:

```
int main(){
    unsigned long long n, a, b, c;
    n = (unsigned long long)pow(2,63)-1;
    a = 99;
    b = 99;
    c = 99;
    cout<<"\nn="<<n<<"  a="<<a<<"  b="<<b<<"  c="<<c<<"    k = "<<f(n, a, b, c);
    cout<<"\nANSWER: "<<findNByBinarySearch(f(n, a, b, c), a, b, c)<<endl;
    n = 1000;
    cout<<"\nn="<<n<<"  a="<<a<<"  b="<<b<<"  c="<<c<<"    k = "<<f(n, a, b, c);
    cout<<"\nANSWER: "<<findNByBinarySearch(f(n, a, b, c), a, b, c)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Then something weird happened.

The code works for the test case `n = (unsigned long long)pow(2,63)-1;`, correctly returning that value of n. But it did not work for `n=1000`. I printed the output and saw the following:

```
n=1000  a=99  b=99  c=99    k = 99000990000

          k= 99000990000
 f(n,a,b,c)= 4611686018427387904  low = 1  mid=4611686018427387904  high = 9223372036854775807
 ...
 ...
          k= 99000990000
 f(n,a,b,c)= 172738215936  low = 1  mid=67108864  high = 134217727

          k= 99000990000
 f(n,a,b,c)= 86369107968  low = 1  mid=33554432  high = 67108863

          k= 99000990000
 f(n,a,b,c)= 129553661952  low = 33554433  mid=50331648  high = 67108863**
 ...
 ...
          k= 99000990000
 f(n,a,b,c)= 423215328047139441  low = 37748737  mid=37748737  high = 37748737
ANSWER: 0
```

Something didn't seem right mathematically. How was it that the value of `f(1000)` was greater than the value of `f(33554432)`?

So I tried the same code in Python, and got the following values:

```
>>> f(1000, 99, 99, 99)
99000990000L
>>> f(33554432, 99, 99, 99)
3740114254432845378355200L
```

So, the value is definitely larger.

### Questions:

- What is happening exactly?
- How should I solve it?

---

Comment: Your function logToBase2Floor should return an unsigned long long but it is returning an int. Either change the function signature or apply the correct cast.

Comment: @Abhishek Right, sorry. I change the code but the problem still persists

Comment: 3740114254432845378355200 a bit larger than 2^63.

Comment: @n.m. Does the value overflow then? I haven't stored the value in a long long int.

Comment: Yes, that's likely the point of this problem.

Comment: @n.m. Okay, I added an important limit to the k value which I had forgotten earlier.

Comment: Maybe I missed something but in your first loop, you set `n = 2^63 / 2` which is `2^62`, then you call `f(n, ...)` but in `f` you have `n^3` which will be `2^186`, which way too large for a `unsigned long long`.

Comment: @Holt Yes, that is part of the problem. We were given test cases like n = 1234567890, but with c=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What is happening exactly?

The problem is here:

```
unsigned long long low = 1;
// Side note: This is simply (2ULL << 62) - 1
unsigned long long high = (unsigned long long)(pow(2, 63)) - 1;
unsigned long long n;
while (/* irrelevant */) {
    n = (low + high) / 2;
    // Some stuff that do not modify n... 
    f(n, a, b, c) // <-- Here!
}
```

In the first iteration, you have `low = 1` and `high = 2^63 - 1`, which mean that `n = 2^63 / 2 = 2^62`. Now, let's look at `f`:

```
#define f(n, a, b, c) (/* I do not care about this... */ + c*n*n*n)
```

You have `n^3` in `f`, so for `n = 2^62`, `n^3 = 2^186`, which is probably way too large for your `unsigned long long` (which is likely to be 64-bits long).

#### How should I solve it?

The main issue here is overflow when doing the binary search, so you should simply handle the overflowing case separatly.

**Preamble:** I am using `ull_t` because I am lazy, and you should avoid macro in C++, prefer using a function and let the compiler inline it. Also, I prefer a loop against using the `log` function to compute the log2  of an `unsigned long long` (see the bottom of this answer for the implementation of `log2` and `is_overflow`).

```
using ull_t = unsigned long long;

constexpr auto f (ull_t n, ull_t a, ull_t b, ull_t c) {
    if (n == 0ULL) { // Avoid log2(0)
        return 0ULL;
    }
    if (is_overflow(n, a, b, c)) {
        return 0ULL;
    }
    return a * n + b * n * log2(n) + c * n * n * n;
}
```

Here is slightly modified binary search version:

```
constexpr auto find_n (ull_t k, ull_t a, ull_t b, ull_t c) {
    constexpr ull_t max = std::numeric_limits<ull_t>::max();
    auto lb = 1ULL, ub = (1ULL << 63) - 1;
    while (lb <= ub) {
        if (ub > max - lb) {
            // This should never happens since ub < 2^63 and lb <= ub so lb + ub < 2^64
            return 0ULL;
        }
        // Compute middle point (no overflow guarantee).
        auto tn = (lb + ub) / 2;
        // If there is an overflow, then change the upper bound.
        if (is_overflow(tn, a, b, c)) {
            ub = tn - 1;
        }
        // Otherwize, do a standard binary search...
        else {
            auto val = f(tn, a, b, c);
            if (val < k) {
                lb = tn + 1;
            }
            else if (val > k) {
                ub = tn - 1;
            }
            else {
                return tn;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0ULL;
}
```

As you can see, there is only one test that is relevant here, which is `is_overflow(tn, a, b, c)` (the first test regarding `lb + ub` is irrelevant here since `ub < 2^63` and `lb <= ub < 2^63` so `ub + lb < 2^64` which is ok for `unsigned long long` in our case).

#### Complete implementation:

```
#include <limits>
#include <type_traits>

using ull_t = unsigned long long;

template <typename T, 
          typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>>
constexpr auto log2 (T n) {
    T log = 0;
    while (n >>= 1) ++log;
    return log;
}

constexpr bool is_overflow (ull_t n, ull_t a, ull_t b, ull_t c) {
    ull_t max = std::numeric_limits<ull_t>::max();
    if (n > max / a) {
        return true;
    }
    if (n > max / b) {
        return true;
    }
    if (b * n > max / log2(n)) {
        return true;
    }
    if (c != 0) {
        if (n > max / c) return true;
        if (c * n > max / n) return true;
        if (c * n * n > max / n) return true;
    }
    if (a * n > max - c * n * n * n) {
        return true;
    }
    if (a * n + c * n * n * n > max - b * n * log2(n)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

constexpr auto f (ull_t n, ull_t a, ull_t b, ull_t c) {
    if (n == 0ULL) {
        return 0ULL;
    }
    if (is_overflow(n, a, b, c)) {
        return 0ULL;
    }
    return a * n + b * n * log2(n) + c * n * n * n;
}

constexpr auto find_n (ull_t k, ull_t a, ull_t b, ull_t c) {
    constexpr ull_t max = std::numeric_limits<ull_t>::max();
    auto lb = 1ULL, ub = (1ULL << 63) - 1;
    while (lb <= ub) {
        if (ub > max - lb) {
            return 0ULL; // Problem here
        }
        auto tn = (lb + ub) / 2;
        if (is_overflow(tn, a, b, c)) {
            ub = tn - 1;
        }
        else {
            auto val = f(tn, a, b, c);
            if (val < k) {
                lb = tn + 1;
            }
            else if (val > k) {
                ub = tn - 1;
            }
            else {
                return tn;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0ULL;
}
```

#### Compile time check:

Below is a little piece of code that you can use to check if the above code at compile time (since everything is `constexpr`):

```
template <unsigned long long n, unsigned long long a, 
          unsigned long long b, unsigned long long c>
struct check: public std::true_type {
    enum {
        k = f(n, a, b, c)
    };
    static_assert(k != 0, "Value out of bound for (n, a, b, c).");
    static_assert(n == find_n(k, a, b, c), "");
};

template <unsigned long long a, 
          unsigned long long b, 
          unsigned long long c>
struct check<0, a, b, c>: public std::true_type {
    static_assert(a != a, "Ambiguous values for n when k = 0.");
};

template <unsigned long long n>
struct check<n, 0, 0, 0>: public std::true_type {
    static_assert(n != n, "Ambiguous values for n when a = b = c = 0.");
};

#define test(n, a, b, c) static_assert(check<n, a, b, c>::value, "");

test(1000, 99, 99, 0);
test(1000, 99, 99, 99);
test(453333, 99, 99, 99);
test(495862, 99, 99, 9);
test(10000000, 1, 1, 0);
```

**Note:** The maximum value of `k` is about `2^63`, so for a given triplet `(a, b, c)`, the maximum value of `n` is the one such as `f(n, a, b, c) < 2 ^ 63` and `f(n + 1, a, b, c) >= 2 ^ 63`. For `a = b = c = 99`, this maximum value is `n = 453333` (empirically found), which is why I tested it above.

Comment: I think this answer is almost correct, but it is defeated when c=0. Then, n can take truly massive values.

Comment: @abhidivekar There should be no issue for "small" values of n, as soon as n gets larger, the problem with lie in the cube (n*n*n), even for `c = 1`. The only side case as you pointed out is when `c = 0`, so you should simply add a check.

Comment: Okay I have edited this answer with a solution I found to work. The question is also now marked answered.

Comment: Why `if (a==99 && b == 99)` ?  What's so magic about that single pair?

Comment: If c is zero, the actual value for `n` is going to be between `k/(a+b*63)` and `k/(a + b)`.  Calculating those values should give a (much) tighter range on the number of bits in `n`, which can be fed back to improve the bounds (for `c` > 0 though, I think binary chop will still be best).

Comment: @MartinBonner This is OP's code edited into my answer. I agree with you that these bounds would be tighter, but you will still get overflow I think: If `a = 0` and `b = 1`, with `k = 2^63 - 2`, you get `n = 2^63 * (1 + 1/63)` which is `9369774767598502406` (no overflow), but once you do `b*n*log2(n)` in `f`, you get `590295810358705651578` which is `2^69` so you there is an overflow.

Comment: @MartinBonner There are only 64 possible values for `log2(n)`, if `c = 0`, I personally would try each of these and simply compute `n = k / (a + b * q)` where `q` range from 1 to 64 (`log2(n)`) and see if one of these match.

Comment: @MartinBonner Actually, I do not think that splitting this method into two cases is useful here. See my edited answer where I simply check at each iteration if the is an overflow, in which case you can start with a really large upper bound and let the algorithm decrease it until it find a feasible value.

Comment: @abhidivekar See my edited answer which do not rely on finding a correct bound and is more robust.

Comment: I agree.  I like that solution - it is "obviously" correct and generalizes readily.  (If this was a performance critical bit of code, there are lots of things one could do to improve the situation - but get it right first, and then make it fast **if necessary**).

Comment: @Holt, this is very useful to know, and I am pleasantly surprised that you spent so much time on this particular question. :)